# Simplify formula of a recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion

I am a software developer, had maths 15 years ago (so I beg for forgiveness if my notation below hurts your eyes), and would like to calculate the number of elements a certain algorithm will produce. The algorithm is implemented, works fine, and I know how to calculate the number of elements using a complex formula:
$$C(n) = n!/(n-1)! + n!/(n-2)! + n!/(n-3)! + ... + n!/0!)$$

```
where:
n = number of input elements (positive integer)
C(n) = count of all generated elements for input of size n
```

E.g.

$$    C(1) = 1!/0! = 1/1 = 1$$
$$    C(2) = 2!/1! + 2!/0! = 2 + 2 = 4$$
$$    C(3) = 3!/2! + 3!/1! + 3!/0! = 3 + 6 + 6 = 15$$
$$    C(4) = 4!/3! + 4!/2! + 4!/1! + 4!/0! = 4 + 12 + 24 + 24 = 64$$
$$    C(5) = 325$$
$$    C(6) = 1956$$
etc.

Is there a way to present the formula in a simpler, more concise way? I tried, but the simplest notation I count come up with is this:

$$C(n) = n + n*(n-1) + n*(n-1)*(n-2) + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) + ... + n*(n-1)*(n-2)* ... * (n-(n-1))$$

Let's take 4 as an example:

$$    C(4) = 4!/3!   + 4!/2!     + 4!/1!       + 4!/0!$$
$$    C(4) = 4*3!/3! + 4*3*2!/2! + 4*3*2*1!/1! + 4*3*2*1*0!/0!$$
$$    C(4) = 4       + 4*3       + 4*3*2       + 4*3*2*1$$

bit it is still complex and I can't generalize it for n. When I think of it, it seems kind of like an arithmetic progression, but there is no common difference. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sequence [A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526) in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/), given by $C(0)=0$ and $C(n)=n\cdot (C(n-1)+1)$. The entry lists some formulas, in particular a rather explicit one:
$$
C(n) = \lfloor e\cdot n! - 1\rfloor,
$$
where $\lfloor - \rfloor$ denotes rounding down. For example
$$
C(6) = \lfloor e\cdot 6! - 1\rfloor = \lfloor 720e -1 \rfloor = \lfloor 1956.163 \rfloor = 1956.
$$
Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for factorials, you can obtain an approximation as
$$
C(n) \approx e\sqrt {2\pi n} \left({\frac {n}{\mathrm {e} }}\right)^{n} - 1.
$$

Comment: Holy Moly, that formula with e works like a charm. This is pure magic.

Comment: Note that $e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$. All the above formula does is multiply by $n!$, get rid of the $n$-th term and by rounding get rid of all the other terms that don't appear in your formula for $C(n)$. It's really just the definition $e$ that makes this work, not a lot of magic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the magical part with the $e$.

We have

$$C(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}= n!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac 1{i!}$$

Now, Taylor ($e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}$) gives
$$e - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac 1{i!} =\frac{e^t}{n!} \text{ with } 0<t<1$$

So, using $t = \frac 12$ we get a very good estimate for $C(n)$ up to $\pm 1$ by

$$C(n) \approx (n!e -\sqrt{e}) \text{ rounded to the nearest integer}$$